# How to Play High resolution youtube video in iPhone?

Tags: ios4, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to play high resolution  YouTube video in my native application this video:**http://www.youtube.com/v/279x-tNx_Gw&hl=de_DE&fs=1** in my application so what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this it may help.

NSString* embedHTML = 
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"body { background-color: transparent; color: white; } ",videourl];
    //NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML];
    if(webView == nil) {
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0,0,200,200);
        webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [self.view addSubview:webView];
    }
    [webView loadHTMLString:embedHTML baseURL:nil];